# A freshly installed Vistual Studio 2010 doesn't detect freshly installed .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

I've got a project for .NET Framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2010 suggests to retarget it to 4.0. It simply doesn't detect 4.5 installation. What to do?

Do not suggest to reinstall, I've done so already.

Comment: I don't think 2010 can target framework 4.5.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Wanna get points for an answer?